# How do launch/shutdown a Docker container before/after a mocha Test for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, docker, mocha.js

We have a NodeJS application that depends on an external database. Currently I run the mocha tests in one of two ways:

- manually start a docker container, run the tests, shutdown the container
- on merge using a github action (service works like a charm)

What I would like to achieve:

Being able to run my tests using `npm run testsuite` that starts my database container, run the mocha test and shut down the container

On investigation I found plenty of tutorials how to run tests inside a container using docker or docker-compose, but nothing how to "just" launch a temp container for the database only.

Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encapsulate your test like so in your package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "docker-compose up -d && mocha && docker-compose down"
  }
}
```

The -d flag will allow the shell to keep processing commands after the container starts. Otherwise the docker container will indefinitely block your shell (and your tests). In case you're not using docker compose, you can always run:

```
docker run -d
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: "The -d flag will allow the shell to keep processing commands after the container starts." so basically it won't even wait for the database to start and then immediately run the tests querying it which will fail? This couldn't be more unhelpful like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you may be starting the test using mocha runtime with `npm test` -- if that's the case you may want to try starting the mocha tests by calling the API directly from a node file.

In your wrapper Node file you can try and start up the container, then start Mocha.

```
//start container

const mocha = new Mocha();
//more config
mocha.run( ...etc )

//shut down container
```